# Compare a dataset in excel with with SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a extract of a dataset like below from mysql tables joins into Excel.

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ student_no     name  age subject   mark  status   updated_date ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1              aaa   18  Subject1   50    A      2015-07-02    ║
║ 2              bbb   19  Subject1   50    A      2015-07-02    ║
║ 3              ccc   20  Subject3   60    A      2015-07-02    ║
║ 4              ddd   21  Subject4   50    A      2015-07-02    ║
║ 5              fff   22  Subject5   70    A      2015-07-02    ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I need to compare every row of the above dataset with my SQL tables (like below queries), if a row of dataset value doesn't exist in the SQL table then I need to change the status from 'A' to 'I' in the particular row from the above dataset.

**SQL query**

```
select 
    std.student_number, std.student_name,
    sa.subject_name, ma.mark 
from 
    student std
join 
    subject sa ON std.student_no = sa.student_no
join 
    marks ma ON sa.subject_id=ma.subject_id
where 
    (std.student_name = 'aaa' 
     and std.age = 18 
     and sa.subject = 'Subject1')

select 
    std.student_number, std.student_name,
    sa.subject_name, ma.mark 
from 
    student std
join 
    subject sa ON std.student_no = sa.student_no
join 
    marks ma ON sa.subject_id = ma.subject_id
where 
    (std.student_name = 'bbb' 
     and std.age = 19 
     and sa.subject = 'Subject1')
```

Do I need to write any .net application to do this or can I do this via SQL Server itself?

Comment: Google `SQL Server Integration Services`

Answer (score 0):

You should use SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) and create a project that will take the Excel file and dump it into a new table and then create a query to compare your original table to the excel table that was imported in the new table.